# In MySQL why is this IF returning false?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

In MySql, if the first argument of an IF() function is a string, why does it return false?

```
SELECT IF('string', 'string', 'not string'); -- 'not string'
```

Of course I could sort of fix this if I did

```
IF(!ISNULL('string'), 'string', 'not string')) -- 'string'
```

or

```
IFNULL('string', 'not string'); -- 'string'
```

It seems somewhat counter-intuitive that it evaluates a string the way that it does seeing as

```
SELECT IF(1, 'one', 'not one'); -- 'one'
```

and

```
SELECT IF('1', 'one', 'not one'); -- 'one'
```

evaluate the way that they do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

> IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
>
> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns
>   expr2; otherwise it returns expr3.
>   IF() returns a numeric or string
>   value, depending on the context in
>   which it is used.

So 1 is true because 1 != 0 and 1 != NULL. This is like what you would see in C.

But for a string, saying a 'test' evaluates to true has no real basis in the definition and does not make logical sense. It needs to be compared to something for a boolean result.

Comment: annoying that SELECT IF('1', 'one', 'not one'); returns 'one'

Comment: And what does SELECT `IF('2', 'two', 'not two');` do??

Answer (score 5):

[The first argument given to `IF()` is a predicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html). A string isn't considered a predicate by MySQL, so it defaults to false. As for your last case, a lot of languages (C, Perl, etc) consider nonzero integers true, so MySQL is simply supporting that paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

Because 'string' is neither true nor false and the first expression should evaluate to a boolean.

Why does IF(1, ...) evaluate to true? Good question. Maybe a throwback to C (i.e. if it's 1, then it's true)?

EDIT: Actually, by the definition of the command at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if, expr1 is TRUE if expr1 <>  0 and expr1  <> NULL, which is the case when expr1 == 1.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but apparently that's handled differently under the hood in MySQL, i.e. the expectation seems to be that a numeric or boolean evaluation is occurring in expr1, which would preclude using a string as the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are similarities in PHP:

```
"string" != 0 // false
"one"    != 0 // false
"1"      != 0 // true
```

The confusion seems to arise because MySQL compares to 0 (and null) to get the boolean value of something. In other languages, like PHP and Javascript, a string, when cast to boolean, returns true when non-empty (or not "0").

```
// php
0 == true          // false
"string" == 0      // true*
"string" == true   // true

// mysql
if(0, "true", "false")   // false
if("string", "true", "false") // false*
```

The two `*`starred`*` lines show the equivalent comparisons, if you know what I mean.