# If Statement in MySQL Select

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

According to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) a if works as follows:

> IF(*expr1*,*expr2*,*expr3*)
>
> If *expr1*  is `TRUE` (*expr1* <> `0` and *expr1* <> `NULL`) then `IF()` returns *expr2*; otherwise it returns *expr3* [...].

Here is a random fiddle that represents my problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8076e2/1

Basically what I'm trying to do is the following:

```
SELECT IF(whatever, 1, 2) FROM testing WHERE whatever = 'abc';
```

Since there is a record there that matches my `WHERE` clause it basically means that `whatever` won't be `0` or `NULL` like specified in the docs. Then why am I getting *expression3* as result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MySQL why is this IF returning false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423326/in-mysql-why-is-this-if-returning-false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expr1` is intended to be a boolean expression, or at least a numeric value, not a string.

You can use `true` and `false`, or `1` and `0`, etc. Technically any non-zero numeric value is interpreted as `true`.

Since you are using the string `'abc'` as `expr1`, MySQL is implicitly converting that to the number `0`, which represents `false`.

In order to return one result for a non-empty string, and another result for empty string or null, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT if((whatever is not null and whatever != ''), 1, 2) 
FROM testing 
WHERE whatever = 'abc';
```

You can also do the same thing with `CASE` if you want to follow the SQL standard:

```
SELECT (case when (whatever is not null and whatever != '') then 1 else 2 end) 
FROM testing 
WHERE whatever = 'abc';
```

Comment: Would it be out of scope to extend your answer just a little bit in order to guide me to a proper way to achieve what I want? In other words, how do I evaluate non-empty string into true?

Comment: No problem. I'll add two example queries to my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(whatever) > 0, 1, 2) FROM testing WHERE whatever = 'abc';
```